# Avoid Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' while services needed for Authentication data

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I'm working on a memory leak on our game server. I diagnosed that it comes from player authentication feauter as we use Unity JWT tokens.

Our server uses authentications like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {         options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = GetRsaKey,
            ValidAudience = "TODO",
            ValidIssuer = "https://player-auth.services.api.unity.com",
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true, 
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
        };

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnTokenValidated = tokenValidationContext =>
            {
                if (!tokenValidationContext.Principal.HasClaim(x => x.Type == "sub"))
                    tokenValidationContext.Fail("Token does not contain data required to identify user");

                var userService = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                var user = userService.GetUserByUnityId(tokenValidationContext.Principal.UnityUserId()).Result;

                if (user == null)
                {
                    tokenValidationContext.Fail("Token does not match any known user");
                }
                else
                {
                    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)tokenValidationContext.Principal.Identity;
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("userid", user.Id.ToString()));
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }; };
.AddJwtBearer("UserRegisterScheme", options =>
    //used for register endpoint to success without user in database 
    { 
        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = GetRsaKey,
            ValidAudience = "TODO",
            ValidIssuer = "https://player-auth.services.api.unity.com",
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
        };

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnTokenValidated = tokenValidationContext =>
            {
                if (!tokenValidationContext.Principal.HasClaim(x => x.Type == "sub"))
                    tokenValidationContext.Fail("Token does not contain data required to identify user");

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
 }
```

Both of the JWT Bearer are creating `TokenValidationParameters` and to set `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` we need to get RSA key. This key is changed and we have to download the current one from the unity http so we created method to do it in our server metadata service.

In Program.cs we have method that returns key, but it uses `builder.Service.BuildServiceProvider()` to get the token from our service. It results in a memory leak so we create multiple singletons. We get warning:

> Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'. server

```
IEnumerable<SecurityKey> GetRsaKey(
    string token,
    SecurityToken securityToken,
    string kid,
    TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters)
{
    var keyParameters = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
        .GetRequiredService<IServerMetadataService>()
        .GetUgsTokenKeySignatureParameters().Result;

    var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters()
    {
        Modulus = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(keyParameters.modulus),
        Exponent = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(keyParameters.exponent),
    };
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create(rsaParameters);
    RsaSecurityKey rsaKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
    return new List<SecurityKey>() { rsaKey };
}
```

The thing is that I can't find a way to fix it. I tried multiple workarounds that I found on the web, but it doesn't work or throws the error that indicates service is changed after `builder.Build()` has been called (Cannot modify `ServiceCollection` after application is built but i need service).

I'm stuck. I can't call service before application is built, because it leaks memory. But I also can't configure authentication after app is built, when I have access to the services.

Edit:
To clarify how I expect it's a memory leak corresponding to this.
I'm querying single endpoint that requires authentication thousands time.

This is Controller code:

```
[HttpGet("global-ranking")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserSeasonViewModel>>> GetGlobalRanking()
    {
        var ranking = await _seasonService.GetGlobalRanking();

        if (ranking == null)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Ranking is empty");
        }
        return Ok(ranking);
    }
```

This is service code (it happens for endpoints that use standard LINQ as well):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserSeasonViewModel>> GetGlobalRanking()
{
    return await _context.UsersSeasonViewModel
        .FromSqlRaw(//query)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

I take 2 snapshots and compare them. After few minutes diff between 2 snapshots: `CancellationTokenSource+CallbackNode (+4000), CancellationTokenSource (+1225), CancellationTokenSource+Registrations (+1222), IList<IDisposable> (+2442), dozen objects related to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger (between +3663 - +407), Action (+815), Thread (+411)`

Leak stops once I turn off authorization.

Comment: How are you so sure that this results in a memory leak? How did you come to this conclusion? What did you measure, how, and what did you find? Although it is true that it is generally not advisable to call `BuildServiceProvider` multiple times, in your case only `IServerMetadataService` (with its dependencies) is resolved. How much memory does this consume, and how much does this cause the application's memory footprint to increase over time? I can't really imagine this causing more than a few kB of memory.

Comment: I edited the post to give you some more insights on how I test the server.

Comment: Where and how is `GetRsaKey` used? That's vital information you've omitted.

Comment: Both implementations of JwtBearer use it to create TokenValidationParameters:

        ```options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = GetRsaKey,
            //Rest of implementation
        };```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Your `GetRsaKey` method is called over and over again, the key isn't cached. In that case, YES!! you have a serious memory leak.

Comment: Where is `IServerMetadataService` coming from? A third-party library? Is it your own code? If it's your own code, please show its registration and it constructor definition.

Comment: This is my own code. It is registered in Program.cs like any other service `builder.Services.AddScoped<IServerMetadataService, ServerMetadataService>();`
Contructor takes only my GameDbContext. My variables are pretty straightforward as well.
    
    `private readonly GameDbContext _context;
    private static string ugsTokenKeyModulus = null;
    private static string ugsTokenKeyExponent = null;
public ServerMetadataService(GameDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }`

Comment: I think I omitted very important part of code. I added implementation of both JwtBearers. It turns out once I swap claimsIdentity to this: ` claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("userid", "Hardcoded_Test_ID");` and delete whole sequence of getting UserId from UserService it doesn't generate objects on stack and Heap Size stay the same. UserService implementation just takes dbContext in constructor, there is no other private variables.
But even with this hardcoded claimIdentity my "Process Memory" in VS Diagnostic Tool grows gradually (but slower then before)

Comment: @Steven how can I cache the key? The key is "cached" in ServerMetadataService as private variables, but I think it's not the solution you think of.

Comment: I know too little of this authorization mechanism to give any feedback on how to cache the key. It depends on, among other things, how long a key can live.

Comment: But in your case, where `ServerMetadataService` is your own code, i'd advice to *not* register `ServerMetadataService` in the DI Container, but rather create `ServerMetadataService` by hand, e.g. `new ServerMetadataService(new GameDbContext(...))`. This circumvents the need to have a container before the container is built.

Comment: I splitted method into AuthenticationService that I create just like that, I don't even need dbContext for it `var authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();`. Now I get keyParameters in GetRsaKey like that `var keyParameters = authenticationService.GetUgsTokenKeySignatureParameters().Result;`. I think that part works well, it get's parameters from web at the server start, then they're cached.

The issue is that memory leak persist, I think it's due to getting userId from UserService in OnTokenValidated.

Comment: I posted a solution that fixes the leak in context of creating new Objects and keeping them on Heap, but I would appreciate comments on that, because I don't think it an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Steven I managed to fix, at least partially, memory leak.

In Program.cs I create instance of AuthenticationService that provides methods used for authenticating user (RSAKeyData + getting userId).

```
var authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();
```

I reworked GetRsaKey to get keyParameters from the service

```
var keyParameters = authenticationService.GetUgsTokenKeySignatureParameters().Result;
```

Now the tricky part comes in. The biggest leak was when I used userService to get userId data in OnTokenValidated.This is how new method looks like

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnTokenValidated = tokenValidationContext =>
            {
                if (!tokenValidationContext.Principal.HasClaim(x => x.Type == "sub"))
                    tokenValidationContext.Fail("Token does not contain data required to identify user");

                var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GameDbContext>();
                optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db"));
                using (var dbContext = new GameDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
                {
                    string userId = tokenValidationContext.Principal.UnityUserId();
                    var user = authenticationService.GetUserByUnityId(userId, dbContext).Result;
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        tokenValidationContext.Fail("Token does not match any known user");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)tokenValidationContext.Principal.Identity;
                        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("userid", user.Id.ToString()));
                    }
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
```

I tested server now and no immediate leaks occur. Snapshots doesn't show growth in Objects or Heap memory. What still concerns me is that "Process Memory" debugged in Visual Studio continues to grow, but much slower then before.

I don't think my solution is the best though. I tried to pass GameDbContext into AuthenticationService like this:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GameDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db"));
var authenticationService = new AuthenticationService(new GameDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
```

This results in a runtime error:

> 'One or more errors occurred. (An attempt was made to use the model
> while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside
> 'OnModelCreating' in any way that makes use of the model that is being
> created.)'

I'm not sure if creating new GameDbContext for every query is acceptable, but I don't know how to avoid it. What I achieved is that it seems to be disposed after authentication unlike getting new IUserService.

Comment: The only thing I improved is defining optionsBuilder outside of authentication so it happens only once. Server with this bugfix is running for 10h for now and it doesn't show any signs of memory leak (old one was working for 3-4h top). I accept this answer, but feel free to suggest more optimized solution. I don't think creating DbContext for every query is performance wise.